# Gradient and image are not overlapping each other

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have an image and I'm attempting to add a gradient to it in my website and put some white text over it. I'm in modern version of chrome for my testing so it should be able to handle it. Here is my html and my css. I've tried this a couple of different ways but every time either the gradient shows, or the picture, but never both overlapped. Is it not possible with the colors I've selected?

```css
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(.25turn, rgb(12, 14, 22), rgb(172, 7, 197)), url("./PulseB2.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  width: 1663px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-text {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <p class="image-text">I exist</p>
</div>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: why dont you try this for starters, put background image and gradient in two different elements and try to reduce opacity of one of them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some transparency to your gradient (e.g. using `rgba` instead of `rgb`), so the background image won't be completely obscured.

```css
background: 
  linear-gradient(.25turn, rgba(12, 14, 22, 0.5), rgba(172, 7, 197, 0.5)), 
  url("./PulseB2.jpg");
```

```css
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(.25turn, rgba(12, 14, 22, 0.5), rgba(172, 7, 197, 0.5)), url("https://picsum.photos/640/480");
  height: 500px;
  width: 1663px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-text {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <p class="image-text">I exist</p>
</div>
```

Another aproach is to add some blend mode to the background using [`background-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode). So the gradient serves as a blender layer.

```
background-blend-mode: screen;
```

```css
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(.25turn, rgb(12, 14, 22), rgb(172, 7, 197)), url("https://picsum.photos/640/480");
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1663px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-text {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <p class="image-text">I exist</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might play with `background-blend-mode` property:

```css
.background {
  background: linear-gradient(.25turn, rgb(12, 14, 22), rgb(172, 7, 197)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/L48bc.jpg);
  background-blend-mode:overlay;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1663px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-text {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <p class="image-text">I exist</p>
</div>
```